# Is there a recommended way to put a copyright notice in a ~.blend file?

Tags: image, file-format, blend-files, text-object

Suppose I have just created a ~.blend file, and I want to include in the file a copyright notice. Two ways I can think of to do it off the top of my heard are to create a plane mesh object, and assign an image texture to it, where the image is a copyright notice; and to create a text object, where the object itself is the copyright notice. I'm sure if I think about it more, I can come up with several other methods, too.

Is there a recommended or generally accepted way to put a copyright notice in a Blend file, perhaps in the file's metadata?

Comment: Usually I see these kinds of things embedded as a text datablock shown in  the text editor. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/15729/599

Comment: a text block is no good, because it does not stay with your object when it's copied or appended into other blend files, and it does not scale to scenes with hundreds or thousands of assets..   Today, the best solution is custom properties, though we need a better solution.